# Outputting a Rails 5.0 Key Value Path as a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm very new to Rails so I'll try and explain this the best I can.  I have a simple `Products` model with one of the fields being the name of the Stripe plan name. This is so a new product can be added and the selection will append the plan name to the end of the path.  It works great hard coded for testing.

Heres my `products/show.html.erb` line in questions.  I am only including this for now as any experienced Rails developer should see the issue.

**products/show.html.erb** hard coded

```
...
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', new_subscription_path(plan: 'monthly'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
...
```

**products/show.html.erb** what I need

```
...
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', new_subscription_path(plan: '<%= @product.stripe_name %>' ), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
...
```

Having <%= @product.stripe_name %> in as a string throws an error.

**The desired outcome would look like this in the browser**

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/subscription/new?plan=monthly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', new_subscription_path(plan: '<%= @product.stripe_name %>' ), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Should be this:

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', new_subscription_path(plan: @product.stripe_name), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

You don't put `<%= ... %>` inside another `<%= ... %>`.

Comment: That won't work because Stripe expects the plan name @product.stripe_name to be a string.

Comment: I did try it, but it just output the new path in browser `http://127.0.0.1:3000/subscription/new`

Comment: A rookie oversight... I forgot to add `:stripe_plan` as a permitted filed in the products_controller.